# Cygnus Fiware docker Error

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I have downloaded the git repository to my server and I have followed the steps in Readme file located at docker folder:

```
docker-compose -f ./docker/0.compose.jar-compiler.yml -p cygnus run --rm compiler
docker build -f ./docker/Dockerfile -t fiware/cygnus .
docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose.yml up
```

However I'm getting a Java error when I'm try to run the last command
/docker-compose.yml up

```
Recreating docker_cygnus_1...
Attaching to docker_cygnus_1
cygnus_1 | + exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95-2.6.4.0.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -cp '/flume/conf:/flume/lib/*:/flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f flume/conf/agent_0.conf -n cygnusagent
cygnus_1 | flume/bin/cygnus-flume-ng: line 232: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95-2.6.4.0.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Can you help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did replicate your steps, this is the output

```
[ root: fiware-cygnus ]# docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose.yml up
Creating docker_cygnus_1
Attaching to docker_cygnus_1
cygnus_1 | + exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95-2.6.4.0.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/flume/conf:/flume/lib/*:/flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f flume/conf/agent_0.conf -n cygnusagent
cygnus_1 | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
cygnus_1 | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/flume/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus_1 | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.12.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus_1 | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
cygnus_1 | 16/02/05 17:19:56 ERROR nodes.CygnusApplication: A fatal error occurred while running. Exception follows. Details=The specified configuration file does not exist: /flume/conf/agent_0.conf
docker_cygnus_1 exited with code 0
```

You need to add the file `/flume/conf/agent_0.conf` with adecquate configuration.

Comment: FWIW: The commit revision I was working was `354c676ed1041a630812874223cb8d83a83e6339`

Comment: I already did it but I'm not able to reach the SLF4J logs. I think I'm missing something in the previous step, before it is reading the conf file. I'm also working with this commit 354c676ed1041a630812874223cb8d83a83e6339

Comment: Shot in the dark: Maybe you are unable to mount your local directories. Do this for me: Step into the directory `target` and execute `docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/testing-dir busybox bash` and inside the machine `ls /testing-dir`. Docker should have mounted the directory from where you are running.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the issue recreating a new image and updating the CentOS container. Now it works, thanks for your help